# how do i talk to a terminal so i can automatically insert a password in ssh?

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

im trying to use python so i will automatically ssh into pinggy.io and then log in by pressing enter cause the password is empty and i dont know how to do it

i want to also after read the information after a log in has happend
so
i could see the generated ip from the tunnel and sending it to my discord webhook

i tried this but it didnt work

```
import subprocess
import time

command = "ssh -p 443 -R0:localhost:8000  -o ServerAliveInterval=30 tcp@a.pinggy.io"

process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
time.sleep(5)
process.stdin.write("\n")
process.stdin.flush()

for line in process.stdout:
    print("Subprocess stdout:", line, end="")

for line in process.stderr:
    print("Subprocess stderr:", line, end="")
```

but when i press enter then it writes what im asking for but it is still clogging the main thread

i probably did a bunch of dumb things cause this is from chatgpt but im asking for help

so basically how do i do read and write to a terminal using python

Comment: Please look into the paramiko python package.

Comment: The smarter way to do this is not to use a password at all, but instead create a public/private key pair.  Also, why are you using port 443?  That's intended for HTTPS, not for SSH.

Comment: Use [sshpass](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ssh-automation-sshpass) or [expect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).